# Video Chat App for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: audio, video, pi-zero-w, streaming-video, p2p

I am searching for an app through which I can send my voice and video feed to another user on laptop using picam and mic module and recieve voice from him.

I am gonna use Raspberry Zero W with picam. I will preferrably use bluetooth headphones for mic and speakers.

Raspi User: Sends voice+video, receives voice
Laptop/Android User: Sends Voice, receives voice+video

I am currently looking into webRTC.

Please suggest alternatives or some related projects. (You can give your view on webRTC too)

This is my first post. If I messed up any guidelines, correct me.

Comment: Are you interested in pre-built solutions or building your own?

Comment: it's almost like you want to build a [Raspberry Pi Video Doorbell](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Smart-Home-Doorbell-for-Less-Than-40/) <== that's the first of many links that came up when I searched for "raspberry pi video doorbell" - now, it may not be exactly what you're doing, but, it does provide the functionality you've described

Answer (score 0):

You can get an alternative called "Whatsapp" by facebook on pi .
Type commands and install [Pi-apps](https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps)

If it shows pi-apps update available , you download is succesful .
When you open it , if it shows where to open click execute in terminal .
Go to "all apps" -> "Whatsapp" -> "install" .
If you already have an account on another device , simple scan the QR code and you will get chat contacts and everything.
Hope you enjoy chatting !